# How to replace values in specific lines and on determined conditions

Tags: matlab, if-statement, replace, find, conditional-statements

I'm in trouble: I have a dataset with 128597 lines and 10 columns.
I need to change the values from column 10 between line 10276 until 128597.

And this change have to respect some conditions, like: 
If the value is between 11 and 33, the value will become 1
If the value is between 34 and 56, the value will become 5
And go on...

I tried the code below, but didn't work:

> m(10276:128597,10) > 11 & m(10276:128597,10)< 33=1;

Can anyone help me please!!! :)

Comment: By this your are getting only indices as logical output. I think you should do: 

m(m(10276:128597,10) > 11 & m(10276:128597,10)< 33)=1;

Comment: Hi John. I tried what you said, but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? what does the ouput look like?

Comment: I looked at the data and the value didn't changed.

Comment: Actually, you are right, it does not work. I will test it carefully

Comment: First, you get the indices which satisfy your condition. Then you add the missed part of the matrix (while searching for a & b). and those are the correct indices satisfying the conditions in the original matrix      :    


[a,b]=(m(10276:128597,10) > 11 & m(10276:128597,10)< 33);
m(a+10275,b+9)=1;

Comment: Please refer to:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967911/range-selection-in-matlab/44968358#44968358

Answer (score 0):

i think this may be help

```
a=[1,2,3;2,3,4;3,2,1;2,4,1];
amask=false(size(a));
amask(2:3,3)= a(2:3,3)>3;
a(amask)=9999;
```

and the ans is

a =

```
 1     2     3
 2     3     4
 3     2     1
 2     4     1
```

a =

```
       1           2           3
       2           3        9999
       3           2           1
       2           4           1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your bins are consecutive, i.e. there are no gaps between the categories, you can use [discretize](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html). Like this you can change all values at once and don't have to use an insane number of logical operators if you have a lot if bins.

```
% edges of the bins. As an example there are currently 3 bins ranging from
% 11 to 34, 34 to 57, 57 to 77. The upper values are included in the next bin, i.e. bin 2 goes from 34.0 to 56.999999
edges = [11 34 57 77];
% Example values you want to give to the bins. Length has to be one shorter than edges
replacementvalues = [1 5 9];

% subset of the data you want to change
subset = m(10276:128597,:);
% bin the subset into categories
binnumber = discretize(subset,edges);
% replace the values in subset that are inside those bins
subset(~isnan(binnumber)) = replacementvalues(binnumber(~isnan(binnumber)));
% replace the values in the original matrix with the updated subset
m(10276:128597,:) = subset;
```

If there are gaps between the bins, the code can be expanded by making a second set of "do not change" bins.