# Range Selection in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I defined a matrix 6 by 6 and want to make a change in values in some ranges.

```
c = floor(rand(6,6) * 100)
```

the result:

```
22    26    10     2     9     3
38    82    90    42    59     6
58    98    87    31    47    31
25    73    81    16    69    53
29    34    26    17    69    65
61    58    59    42    63    40
```

then I run:

```
c(c(1:3,:)<17) = 0

22     0     0     2     9     3
38    82    90    42    59     6
58    98    87    31    47    31
25     0     0    16    69    53
29    34     0    17    69    65
61    58    59    42    63    40
```

I want to make elements in rows between 1 and 3 which are less than 17 zero, but the result seems wrong to me! any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not work because you are getting linear indices from your condition and the size of the submatrix is different from that of the original one. 
You can first get the subscripts and then change your original matrix:

```
c = floor(rand(6,6) * 100)
c =

28    60    24    48    20    99
 0    78    34    80    38    70
49    11    54    37    66     8
98    57     6    51    75     4
73    87    41     9    17    49
31    68    23    90    51    44

[a,b]=find(c(1:3,:)<17);
c(sub2ind(size(c),a,b))=0
c =

28    60    24    48    20    99
 0    78    34    80    38    70
49     0    54    37    66     0
98    57     6    51    75     4
73    87    41     9    17    49
31    68    23    90    51    44
```

please note that if you dont start from the first row or the first column, you should consider the difference:

```
[a,b]=find(c(3:6,2:5)<17);
c(sub2ind(size(c),a+2,b+1))=0
```

Another solution is to create a mask matrix of indicies to use for the substitution. This would also work in the general case of not starting from the first row or column:

```
idx = zeros(size(c));
idx(1:3,:) = c(1:3,:)<17;
c(idx==1) = 0
```

Comment: Good solution (+1). You might also add to your answer that it is possible to first build a matrix of indicies to use for the substitution. This would also work in the general case of not starting from the first row or column. `idx = zeros(size(c)); idx(1:3,:) = c(1:3,:)<17; c(idx==1) = 0`

Comment: If I understand correctly, this zeros out a rectangle which includes the desired entries, but also other entries; which is not what the OP wants

Comment: @LuisMendo After actually testing the code, I agree that the solution as stated is incorrect.

Comment: You should probably delete it / edit it then, to avoid confusion

Comment: How is it possible to zero out other entries? I will show the example in the answer. If I missed something, please mention it.

Comment: @LuisMendo I confirmed that it works perfectly, so please read carfully the question and the answer

Comment: Try `c=magic(4), [a,b]=find(c(1:3,:)<9); c(a,b)=0` in order to see the problem

Comment: @John Note that you have incorrectly zeoed out the 82 and the 33 in the top half.

Comment: Right, I will delete the answer. This how it should work.

Comment: @John Feel free to instead include the solution I mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: Please note that since your answer is accepted you cannot delete it. Whether that means that the OP isn't sure about their requirements themselves, or was as confused as we were due to the example numbers is unsure of course; the option besides deleting is to ask the OP to edit their post to clarify their needs, which might be in accordance with this answer, since it is accepted.

Comment: With `sub2ind` it works. But note that the _Another solution_ part is still incorrect

Comment: You should tell the OP about the change. They accepted the answer in its previus incorrect form and are probably using it

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't see why you insisted my additional solution should be removed from the answer. I belive it is correct.

Comment: @user1884905 I am testing it also to make sure that it works.

Comment: @LuisMendo The other solution is also working, I will readd it to the answer

Comment: @user1884905 Sorry, that part is correct. I got confused

Answer (score 2):

Use a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) built from two conditions: element is less than the threshold and row index is within the set of target rows.

```
th = 17;                                                  % threshold
rows = [1 2 3];                                           % target rows
ind = bsxfun(@and, c<th, ismember(1:size(c,1), rows).');  % logical index 
c(ind) = 0;                                               % set entries to 0
```

For your example input

```
c = [22    26    10     2     9     3
     38    82    90    42    59     6
     58    98    87    31    47    31
     25    73    81    16    69    53
     29    34    26    17    69    65
     61    58    59    42    63    40]
```

this gives

```
c =
    22    26     0     0     0     0
    38    82    90    42    59     0
    58    98    87    31    47    31
    25    73    81    16    69    53
    29    34    26    17    69    65
    61    58    59    42    63    40
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that multiplies the matrix with a logical mask:

```
c(1:3,:) = c(1:3,:) .* c(1:3,:) >= 17;
```